"Boundary" between convergent and divergent series of the form 1/n^m.
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, is there some $m \in \mathbb{R}$, with $1 < m < 2$ that defines the "boundary" between convergence and divergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^m}$?

A well-known result is that $p$-series is convergent iff $p>1$. This can be proved with integral test. And so for your question, there is no such $m$.

Where do you think the boundary is? EG What do you know about $ \sum 1/ n^{3/2} $?

More generally, there is no “smallest divergent series” (nor is there any “largest convergent series”). Indeed, for any integer $k\ge0$, the series $$\sum\frac1{n^{m_0}{(\log n)}^{m_1}{(\log\log n)}^{m_2}\cdots{(\underbrace{\log\log\cdots\log}_k,n)}^{m_k}}$$
is convergent if and only if $(m_0,m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k)>(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ for the lexicographic ordering.

An older discussion here

Thank you, I always find that my intuition breaks down when working with infinities.
